# Send Keyboard characters VBA

Tags: html, windows, vba, excel, sendkeys

Is `SendKeys` the only way to send a combinaison of letters from the keyboard ?

I have to deal with a Webpage Dialog box which can't be activated so I thought about using `SendKeys` on it but for some reasons, nothing happens.
This box is triggered when I click on a button "Export file".

I realized that from the time this box is being opened until it is closed, the code is not running which means that if I run the following bit with F8, it will click to open the box -> box is displayed -> but the `SendKeys` command seems to be reached only after I manually close that box.

[image]

```
objIE.document.frames(1).frames(0).document.ChildNodes(1).Children(1).Children(0).Children(0).Children(4).Children(0).Click ' clicks on the Export button
SendKeys "mymailaddress@mycompany.com", True ' doesn't work...with True or False
```

FYI this is the html of that button I click on and what it triggers :

[image]

This is an intranet page but I found a similar way to get this :

1. Start the creation of a new question on this platform
2. Write some stuff and then attempt to click on your profile button.
3. You'll get this box appearing asking you if you want to *Leave this page* or *Stay on this page*.

If you do those first steps via VBA you'll see that as soon as this box appears, the code won't be activated anymore.
So whatever follows the click on your profile button and, as a result, the display of that box, won't be reached until you manually close that box.

[image]

Comment: `SendKeys` is highly unreliable. You may try to solve that not using IE at all, e. g. via XHRs. Is the URL accessible via internet to make some testing?

Comment: no unfortunately it's an intranet. I am absolutely not familiar with XHR but I will check this out.

Comment: Actually a great similar example would be if you start asking a new question and try to leave the page via vba. You'll get this box offering you to either _Leave this page_ either _Stay on this page_ and you'll see that the code won't be accessible until you close that box manually

Answer (score 0):

The question is where is the focus on the form on initiation? Fact is that the focus could be possible pointed on the form itself or buttons or other components and that is where the SendKeys then sending the data to.

Try to combine the code with:
SendKeys "{TAB}"

Which is tabulator, you can put multiple times until you get focus on the textfield, once focused on correct filed, go with your SendKeys "my message".

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work unfortunately. I editted my question to make it a bit clearer